# UITableViewController flickering behavior

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cosmicmind

I have problem connected with `UITableViewController` flickering.

This is presented in this video [link](http://sendvid.com/2hktkn30).

I am presenting UITableViewController like this :

```
func balanceAction() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainView")
        presentView(view:controller)
}

fileprivate func presentView(view: UIViewController) {

        (navigationDrawerController?.rootViewController as? ToolbarController)?.transition(to: view, duration: 0.3)
}
```

And method from the lib:

```
/**
 A method to swap rootViewController objects.
 - Parameter toViewController: The UIViewController to swap
 with the active rootViewController.
 - Parameter duration: A TimeInterval that sets the
 animation duration of the transition.
 - Parameter options: UIViewAnimationOptions thst are used
 when animating the transition from the active rootViewController
 to the toViewController.
 - Parameter animations: An animation block that is executed during
 the transition from the active rootViewController
 to the toViewController.
 - Parameter completion: A completion block that is execited after
 the transition animation from the active rootViewController
 to the toViewController has completed.
 */
open func transition(to viewController: UIViewController, duration: TimeInterval, options: UIViewAnimationOptions = [], animations: (() -> Void)? = nil, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {

    rootViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    addChildViewController(viewController)
    viewController.view.frame = rootViewController.view.bounds
    transition(from: rootViewController,
        to: viewController,
        duration: duration,
        options: options,
        animations: animations) { [weak self, viewController = viewController, completion = completion] (result) in
            guard let s = self else {
                return
            }

            viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: s)
            s.rootViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
            s.rootViewController = viewController
            s.rootViewController.view.clipsToBounds = true
            s.rootViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            s.rootViewController.view.contentScaleFactor = Device.scale
            completion?(result)
        }
}
```

And the `MainView()`.

```
class MainView: UITableViewController {

    var data = BalanceViewController()

    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = Color.grey.lighten5

        prepearTableView()
        prepareToolbar()
    }

    private func prepearTableView() {
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "BalanceCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "BalanceCell")
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
        self.tableView.dataSource = data
        self.tableView.delegate = self
    }

    private func prepareToolbar() {
        guard let tc = toolbarController else {
            return
        }
        tc.toolbar.title = "Balance report"
        tc.toolbar.detail = "Lifelong overall report"
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return balanceCellHeight
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code that is associated with the "MainView" controller ?

Comment: @CosmicMind i update my question

Comment: That transition code looks strange, have you tried disabling it?

Comment: @redent84 i do not like to modify third party libs it is bad practice

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk That's not what I'm saying. Just don't call that method and replace the view controllers without animation. That way you can check if the issue is in the animation or somewhere else.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk Also, improving open source libraries and sending pull requests if you find an error is a good practice ;)

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk the transition code moves one VC to another using the iOS transition method. The steps there are really to handle the redundant steps needed to correctly transition. I think the issue might be with your TableView calculations. I would recommend creating an issue at the repo, and if possible sending a sample project to support@cosmicmind.com. I need to see more of what is going on.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk we are solving issue [here - Material Issue 610](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/issues/610#issuecomment-262829249), seems to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for any delay, I was able to reproduce the issue and posted a fix, which should work based on my reproduction. Please try [Material 2.3.18](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/releases/tag/2.3.18).

Thank you and all the best :)